# What kind of symfony relationship would be most appropriate?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 2 entities:

A Package, and a StockItem.

A Package can have many Stockitems, and a StockItem can belong to many Packages, so i assume this is a ManyToMany relationship.

But i dont want the StockItems to point towards Packages, cause i assume this will bloat the database.

Since there will be a lot of packages with many more StockItems.

Is it possible to have the Package have an Array of StockItems, while the stockitem does not have a field pointing towards the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ManyToMany` relationship does seem appropriate. You shouldn't have any trouble with this since `ManyToMany` uses a join table which handles all foreign keys, which means neither of your entities will actually have a field pointing towards the other in the database.
Take a look at Doctrine's documentation : [Many-To-Many, Unidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

Check the generated SQL query in the example :

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE users_groups (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    group_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, group_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Group (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE users_groups ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id);
ALTER TABLE users_groups ADD FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES Group(id);
```

As you can see, a `ManyToMany` relationship got created between `User` and `Group` but the only table holding foreign keys is the join table `users_groups`.

Now it's up to you to decide wether the relationship should be unidirectional or bidirectional ([Many-To-Many, Bidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)). You can even choose an owning side in the relation for code readability purposes ([Owning and Inverse Side on a ManyToMany association](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association))